# Qt Layouts Spacers Size

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I have created 2 Push-Buttons in a horizontal layout. Then I added a spacer but it's almost invisible. I also cannot change the size of this spacer.
I cannot change **ANY** size in any layouts! I tried everything, changed the size policy etc. but nothing worked. I watched this video where this guy created two push buttons and put them together in a horizontal layout. 
He added a spacer, just like me, and he was able to change the size it! :

[Qt Layout Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2edb0VOkx-k&list=SP2D1942A4688E9D63&index=6)

What am I doing wrong? I did exactly what he did but it won't work >.< So how can I change the size of the items in a layout (particularly the spacer's size)?

Comment: A spacer is not a widget. It's just an empty space. If you want to change your buttons' sizes - you should change your buttons' properties `minimumSize`. If you want your spacer to be larger - your should resize your window, which contains it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `QBoxLayout::addStretch()` instead of `addSpacerItem()` or `addSpacing()`.